# Adding Multiple Files to an Outlook Message using Access 2010

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

I'm trying to add a Generated report along with multiple .pdf documents in a local folder to an Outlook email using VBA Access 2010.

If it's not possible, I was wondering if there is some sort of workaround, like adding the files to an already open email message, or combining the pdfs into one pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Outlook Object Model to create a new email.  See here for the basics:

Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869289(v=office.15).aspx

Use Application.CreateItem to create a new email.  Then use the returned MailItem object to access MailItem.Attachments, then use Attachments.Add to add files to the email as required.  You can set other MailItem properties (like Subject, To and Body) before calling the Send method.